# Getting hold of metadata when creating a post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am using the save_post action to inspect a metadata field in a custom post and take some action on that value. This is the essential guts of how I am doing it:

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_save_post');

function my_save_post($post_id)
{
    // Check if not autosaving, processing correct post type etc.
    // ...

    // Get the custom field value.
    $my_field_value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_field', true);

    // Do some action
    // ...
}
```

This works fine when updating the post through the admin page. However, when first creating the post, the `my_field_value` is always empty. The field does get saved correctly, but this action trigger does not seem to be able to see it, nor any other custom field values.

I would like the action to be performed on all posts of this type created, and I will be importing many through the CSV Imported plugin. Even then, the custom fields do get imported correctly, and the action trigger does get fired for each row imported, but the save_post action still cannot see the custom field value.

So far as I can see from documentation, the post has already been created by the time this action fires, so I should always be able to see that custom metafield.

---

The answer, it seems, is in the order in which things happen. When creating a post from a form, the custom fields are all collected by the appropriate actions and added to the post before my save_post action fires. This means my trigger is able to see those custom field values.

When importing from CSV, the basic post is created first, and then the custom metafields are added. The save_post trigger fires on the first creation, before the metafields are added, and so the custom field data is not visible to the save_post action.

My solution was to catch the updates of the metadata using the `updated_post_meta` and `added_post_meta` actions *as well as* the `save_post` action:

```
add_action('updated_post_meta', 'my_updated_post_meta', 10, 4);
add_action('added_post_meta', 'my_updated_post_meta', 10, 4);

function my_updated_post_meta($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)
{
    // Make sure we are handling just the meta field we are interested in.
    if ($meta_key != 'my_custom_field') return;
    if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) return;
    if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'my_post_type') return;
    if (trim($meta_value) == '') return;

    // Do my custom task (linking this post to a parent post in a different
    // post type). This is the same task performed by the save_post action.
    my_link_product_track($post_id, trim($meta_value));
}
```

That is essentially what I do, and it seems to work well. I do encapsulate all the above into a custom class in the theme, and don't recommend using global scope variables as shown here, but this is just to show the method.

Comment: Some additional info: the custom field is managed through the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. After importing posts, if I edit any of the posts and save ("Update") them, then my_field_value is set and my subsequent action using that value succeeds. When creating posts, I have logged the value of my_field_value and `get_post_meta($post_id)` in this save_post action, and the metafield values really cannot be seen.

Comment: Similarly, `get_post_custom($post_id)` and its related functions return empty arrays (I am careful the post_id is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure how to close this. Do I mark it as answered by self, or can I share the answer with Alex Demchak, who pointed me in a direction I didn't consider?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at using `$post->ID` instead of `$post_id` -

```
$my_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_field', true);
```

[get_post_meta in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Examples)

**EDIT**:

Could you do something like this?

```
if($post->ID == ''){
    $pid = $post_id;
} else {
    $pid = $post->ID;
}

//$pid = $post->ID or $post_id, whichever contains a value
$my_field_value = get_post_meta($pid, 'my_field', true);
```

something that looks for a value in $post->ID and $post_id, and uses whichever one isn't blank?

Comment: $post->ID works slightly better. It allows the meta field to be read when creating the post through the admin form. It does not work when creating through a CSV import though. When importing via CSV, `$post_id` does contain the post ID, while `$post->ID` does not. I assume $post is only available when handling posts from forms?

Comment: So echoing values when importing CSV records into the post type: I can see the post IDs, and pass the correct IDs into get_post_meta(), but when called during post creation `get_post_meta()` returns only empty fields. During update it returns the correct stored values.

Comment: added edit to answer. Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with CSVi -> Post. Maybe you could check for which variable has a value in the import process, as reflected by the edit above?

Comment: Yes - that's what I did when you first suggested using `$post->ID` - I take whichever one is set, and one of the two always is.

Comment: Great minds think alike I suppose :). Umm, are you making use of [add_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) and [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) properly in your hook to `save_post`? That's the only place I could see drawing that error since it's on the hook :/

Comment: I'm not actually changing the metadata - I just want to inspect it, so that I can use it to perform further actions (actually I'm linking the post to a parent post using a call to the Posts2Posts plugin API).

Comment: Something else you mentioned has let me to where the problem possibly is: "not experienced with CSV importer". I have taken a look at how it works. For each row, it creates the basic core post using `wp_insert_post()`. *Then* it adds on the custom fields using `add_post_meta()`. So, at the time the save_post action fires, when importing from CSV, the meta fields do not yet exist. I will have to follow this up with the CSV Importer author. When creating from a form, the hooks reading the custom fields operate earlier, *before* the save_post action.